# how to create a dynamic menu in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i have a problem in listing category in codeigniter
my table is:

```
    id    name      sub_category   category_name    desc     status
    3    submenu1       menu1      category1        desc1      1
    4    submenu1       menu2      category1        desc1      1
    5    submenu1       menu1      category2        desc1      1
    6    submenu1       menu2      category2        desc1      1
```

my expected output is:

```
 category1
   submenu1 
     menu1
     menu2

 category2
   submenu1 
     menu1
     menu2
```

list like this kind of structure

Mycontroller:

```
    public function index(){
// $this->load->view('view_admin/home');
$data['menu']=$this->Admin_model->menu();
$data['menu1']=$this->Admin_model->menu1();
$data['menu2']=$this->Admin_model->menu2();
echo '<pre>';
print_r($data['menu1']);
echo '</pre>';
$this->load->view('view_admin/banner',$data);
}
```

Mymodel:

```
 function menu(){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('productpage');
    $this->db->where('status',1);
    $this->db->group_by('category_name');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result();
    return $result;
}
function menu1(){
    $this->db->select('*,group(');
    $this->db->from('productpage');
    $this->db->where('status',1);
    $this->db->group_by('name');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result();
    return $result;
}
function menu2(){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('productpage');
    $this->db->where('status',1);
    $this->db->group_by('sub_category');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result();
    return $result;
}
```

i was get an error like this 
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: view_admin/banner.php

Line Number: 58

how to create a for each loop in view to get an expected output

Thank You for your valuable response

Comment: You don't need a method for each menu, you can pass the ID as an argument. Update your question with the code in the line 58

Comment: thank you for response please be give some code for views how to show my expected output. i am really struggled

Comment: I can't give you a code. I have no idea what's the data's structure nor what you have tried so far. Do what I said in the 1st comment and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: ok thank you for your response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need one query/model function and to rearrange your array a bit before the view:

Model:

```
function menu(){
    return $this->db->get_where('productpage', array('status' => 1))->result_array();
}
```

Controller:

```
$array = $this->Admin_model->menu();
$menu = array();
foreach ($array as $item) {
    // rearrange things
    $menu[$item['category_name']][$item['name']][] = $item['sub_category'];
}
$this->load->view('view_admin/banner', array('menu_data' => $menu));
```

View:

```
foreach ($menu_data as $cat_name => $sub_menu) {
    echo $cat_name . '<br>';
    foreach ($sub_menu as $sub_menu_name => $menus) {
        echo $sub_menu_name . '<br>';
        foreach ($menus as $menu) {
            echo $menu . '<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

Generates:

```
category1
submenu1
menu1
menu2
category2
submenu1
menu1
menu2
```